# Can't understand which scope will be associated with DOM node

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When you attach any controller to DOM node, for example,

`<div ng-controller="myController">{{testProperty}}</div>`

controller scope will be associated with this DOM node.
Imagine another example. We created directive myDirective, which has its own isolated scope. Now we have

```
<div ng-controller="myController" myDirective>{{testProperty}}</div>
```

Which scope will be associated with DOM node in this case? Scope of controller or directive? And last example, we have one more directive mySecondDirective with its own isolated
scope

```
<div myDirective mySecondDirective>{{testProperty}}</div>
```

Which scope will be associated with DOM node in this case? Scope of myDirective or mySecondDirective? And can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

> `<div myDirective mySecondDirective>{{testProperty}}</div>`

for `multiple directives defined on a single DOM element`, you can explicitly define a `priority:` - see this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object

---

> `<div ng-controller="myController" myDirective>{{testProperty}}</div>`
>   Which scope will be associated with DOM node in this case? Scope of
>   controller or directive?

for `controller's $scope and a directive's scope defined on a single DOM element`: 
 "The `transclude` option changes the way scopes are nested. It makes it so that the contents of a transcluded directive have whatever scope is outside the directive, rather than whatever scope is on the inside. In doing so, it gives the contents access to the outside scope." from the angularjs docs found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, but all of you are wrong. As I found out it is not possible to create two or more scopes on one DOM node. Angular throws this error:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [pTest2, pTest] asking for new/isolated scope on: <p-test p-test2="">
```

Comment: so the answer i posted is straight from the angularjs docs. perhaps you should post your entire code because your implementation might be causing conflicts with something else or maybe you found a bug, who knows - instead of saying that "all of you are wrong"? lol. Apparently, if you are using `ng-repeat` (not shown in your original post) it might cause some concerns as discussed here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386637/using-multiple-angularjs-directives-in-one-div-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386637/using-multiple-angularjs-directives-in-one-div-tag)

Comment: You were right about "you can explicitly define a priority". You can define two directives on one DOM node with their childs scopes(scope: true), but only one scope, common for both, will be created. And you can't define two directives on one DOM node if one of them has child scope(scope:true) and the other one has isolated scope(scope:{}), angular will throw error. It was my question, I did not ask about directive priority, I asked what will happen if two directives has its own child scopes or isolated scopes.